# emit signal to window

Tags: gtk3, gtkmm3

I have the following code fragments:

```
win = new Gtk::Window;
m_canvas = new Goocanvas::Canvas;

sigc::connection conn_t1 = m_canvas->signal_event().connect( sigc::ptr_fun( &AnyEvent));

sigc::connection conn_t2 = win->signal_event().connect( sigc::ptr_fun( &WinHandler));
```

Now I also register an IdleHandler which generates signals:

```
Glib::signal_idle().connect( sigc::mem_fun( *this, &IdleSendEvent::Do));
```

What I want to achieve:
The handler of the canvas should receive an event and should generate a new one and this one should send to the object, so that it will call again the handler of the m_canvas->signal_event().

In other words: Indirectly via the Idle Handler the signal should be send to the sending object itself.

But if I fire to

```
g_signal_emit_by_name (m_canvas->gobj(), "button-press-event", event, &return_val);
```

the signal is not received in the canvas itself, but in some child objects there.

Q: How to emmit again to the canvas? Is there something like "get_the_parent_signal_object_handler_father_receiver" or something strange?

I did a lot of gtk_widget_get_parent_window() but all results in runtime errors like:

> (go:15430): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: gsignal.c:3484: signal name 'button-press-event' is invalid for instance '0x9afbc48' of type 'GdkX11Window'

I simply have no idea where to find the correct instance which I have to emmit a signal which is then received for the canvas. It looks that the instance for `g_signal_emit_by_name` fires not to the object itself but all child instances. I can not find a documentation how the signals are processed and how the hierarchy can be walked through. One of the problems is that gtk+ and gtkmm are related but the documentation totally unclear and scattered.

Answer (score 1):

You can't emit a signal *to* a particular object. You can only emit a signal *from* an object, that will be received by any signal handlers that are connected to that signal of the emitting object. Objects don't receive signals, only signal handlers do. (Although the signal handler may be, for example, a method of an object.)

The first argument of `g_signal_emit_by_name()` must be the emitting object.

To make a signal handler receive a signal, use `g_signal_connect(emitter, signal_name, handler, user_data)` or its C++ equivalent, `sigc::signal::connect()` as you have done in the example code above.